# How can i modify F5 event inside of a iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, refresh

I want to know how can i get the `F5` to use it inside of an `iframe`, because i did it but outside of it, in my page. I rewrite the URL of my page with this:

```
 window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'OFRAME');
```

and when i tried to refresh it  i got an error, but i fixed it, with this:

```
var URLactual = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
if (URLactual == '') {

    URLactual = window.parent.location.href;
}
window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'OFRAME');
$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        window.location.assign(URLactual);            
    }
});
```

});

So it works but only in my first page, when navigate inside of the page that contains my `iframe` and i press `F5`, i don't know why or how but it doesn't read the `script`.

After that i press again `F5` and the `script` works normally but doesn't do what need to do.

Comment: Iframes have their own windows and when focused the events occur in that window with no knowledge of or bubbling to parent window listeners. If iframe is from a different origin than main page (protocol, domain, subdomain or port) you can't access it's window using script from parent unless you control the code in both

Comment: So... is iframe from same origin as page?

Comment: as the page that shows?

Comment: Yes...as in  main page from example.com and iframe page from example.com

Comment: No it's not :/ So what can i do? could i refresh in other way my iframe? I have access to those pages that my iframe shows

Comment: There is no way to capture events (mouse, keyboard, touch etc) that occur within the iframe window then

Comment: aaawwww maan :/ thanks, so i need to think in othey way to do what i try it

Comment: Is all because of security issues that iframes from another site can exploit if they weren't isolated. Is called "same origin policy"

Comment: thanks bro, i learned something really important :D